# Equivalente ao Google Ngram Viewer?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, recursos-online

Existe algum equivalente ao Google Ngram Viewer para comparar a utilização de palavras portuguesas?

Comment: Esta pergunta deveria estar no META e não aqui. https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on the META site for Portuguese.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode procurar por *corpora* em português. Exemplo:

https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/

Mas ele não possui aquele gráfico de utilização da palavra conforme a época.

Existem outros *corpora*. Basta você pesquisar no Google.